# How do I run shell commands on the device I'm currently using for Android Terminal Emulator?

Tags: adb

I don't have an available PC that I can install ADB on without getting in trouble, and my phone's screen density is killing me. Is there a way I can run adb shell wm density and adb reboot from my own device and not have another device available?

Comment: If your device is rooted just open terminal, and type `su`, then `wm density <value>`, e.g `wm density 400` then reboot.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat My device does not have root. Is there any way to do this without root?

Comment: Not that I know of..

Comment: Run `wm` command in Terminal emulator as: `/system/bin/wm`. But it will show a permission issue `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` because that app has root permission.